# How to get the device's uuid and model information in ionic based App?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have this piece of code in order to recognize/get the device information.

```
ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
    // will execute when device is ready, or immediately if the device is already ready.
    $scope.deviceInformation = ionic.Platform.device();
    $scope.currentPlatform = ionic.Platform.platform();
    $scope.currentPlatformVersion = ionic.Platform.version();
});
```

as per the documentation given [Here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/).
The `ionic.Platform.device();` will return object that is returned to it by cordova. So in the object of cordova the object should contain information of uuid, version, model etc. The documentation is [Here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device)

So i tried to get the uuid and model from the object `deviceInformation` and built and seen the app in mobile, then it shows me `undefined` in the alert.

I have shown it like this:

```
$scope.getDeviceInfo = function() {
    alert($scope.deviceInformation.uuid);
}
```

How can i get the details of object returned my cordova to ionic??

Comment: You are trying to make an alert before the variable has been set up(hence undefined value). I don't know the api you are using but if you try something like this : setTimeout(function(){ alert(uuid); }, 3000); , I think it will get you something

Comment: can you verify cordova plugin available : cordova plugin list
You need to have cordova-plugin-device to get device uuid

Comment: i have tried adding cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device but it shows me 404 error the plugin not found on source location. The regisrty has been moved to npm and i didnt get further of what is is saying...

Comment: i want to know, even after adding ng-cordova.js into js folder of our app, do we have to add the plugins separately that we want to use in our app???

Comment: yes, ng-cordova is angular Directives for Cordova modules. It will not remplace Cordova plugins that abstract the call of Native functions

Comment: i mean that ng-cordova having some plugins like $cordovaCamera, $cordovaDevice etc. These plugins are in ng-cordova. Then if i have added the ng-cordova.js then still do i need to install the camera and device plugins from ng-cordova's github locality to my project in order to make them work or only adding ng-cordova.js is sufficient???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was suffering with the same problem. I got what you need after long search->try->implement->erase->new try cycle. Though i followed ng-cordova plugins, i came to know that adding ng-cordova.js will not make it easy to resolve the plugin problem bcoz it just contain the initialization of plugins that are supported by the ng-cordova on its website. I have followed the steps given [Here on native cordova site](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html)

Point to note here is ng-cordova.js internally calls the methods and API's od native cordova so it is very important to install the cordova plugins separately even after you install the ng-cordova.js. 
Then i initialized the device in `app.module`:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  $scope.deviceInformation = ionic.Platform.device();
});
```

and i called the method in my intro controller:

```
$scope.getDeviceInfo = function() {
  alert($scope.deviceInformation.uuid);
}
```

That gave me all that i need....

Comment: dunno why the same code doesn't work for me... did you make any other changes outside the app.js?

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned the value to a Javascript variable named `deviceInformation`. So you won't get access to AngularJs' `$scope.deviceInformation`.

Change your `var` to `$scope`:

```
ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
    // will execute when device is ready, or immediately if the device is already ready.
    $scope.deviceInformation = ionic.Platform.device();
    $scope.currentPlatform = ionic.Platform.platform();
    $scope.currentPlatformVersion = ionic.Platform.version();
    $scope.getDeviceInfo = function() {
        alert($scope.deviceInformation.uuid);
    }
});
```

You could also use `alert(deviceInformation.uuid);` but you should stick to `$scope` in AngularJS, because it allows simple binding with the HTML using [expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Comment: i have updated my question i have been using $scope after this question added, nut the error is still there

Comment: console.log will not be showing anything as it is running on web browser. The device info will be shown on device when the app will run on device. There i am getting nothing

Answer (score 0):

I got this by simply using following code in device ready function

```
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() { 
   var deviceInformation = ionic.Platform.device();
   console.log('platform: ' +  deviceInformation.platform);
   console.log('udid: ' + deviceInformation.uuid);
   });
```

---

---

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { Device } from 'ionic-native';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@NgModule({
            declarations: [
    ],
    imports: [
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
    ],
    providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        Device,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { Device } from 'ionic-native';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@Component({
            templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp{
>
    rootPage:any = HomePage;
    deviceName: string = '';
>
    constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {

            platform.ready().then(() ={
                        // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
                        // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
                        statusBar.styleDefault();
                        splashScreen.hide();

                    });

            document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady, false);
        }

    onDeviceReady() {
            console.log(Device.uuid);
            console.log(Device.manufacturer);
        }
}
```