# Using ionic.Platform to get device info

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Unable to get device info in view -

```
angular.module('PlatformApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('PlatformCtrl', function($scope) {

  ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
// will execute when device is ready, or immediately if the device is already ready.
  });

var deviceInformation = ionic.Platform.device(); 
});
```

How do I get the device info from the var deviceInformation?

I know deviceInformation.model will retrieve the model name for the device - but the guide on the Ionic site doesn't show how this is done? Everything I seem to try doesn't appear to work getting blank/empty object.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/

Comment: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/device/

Comment: You test in device or in browser

Comment: both :( i'll post some more code shortly

Answer (score 2):

You need to place your code in platform ready as like follow.

```
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
   $scope.deviceInformation = ionic.Platform.device();
  });
```

and you will be available with device information in your controller:

```
 $scope.getDeviceInfo = function() {
   alert($scope.deviceInformation.uuid);
 }
```

For more information some how similar question are available on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799027/how-to-get-the-devices-uuid-and-model-information-in-ionic-based-app) .

Hopes this will help you !